# Would it be possible that the search icon in the search box to actually trigger the search?

Tags: feature-request, search

In lots of sites users can also click on the search icon instead of pressing enter to search. I think it would be a good idea to add this functionality here too and it wouldn't be hard at all.

Sometimes I copy something in the search box and I am used to use my mouse to search too. It seems a little bit strange for me to use the mouse to fill the search box and then push a button on the keyboard to search.

Comment: I don't understand why it's so unnatural to use a keyboard key to search, especially since you just used the keyboard to type your search term. I'd be more interested if there's a usability issue for people using assistive technology or alternate browsers.

Comment: I surf the internet from my bed only with my mouse plenty of times. I do not have a wireless keyboard. That would be my reasoning, but I think the best reason would be that it is just extremely simple to do.

Comment: Then how do you type? If you are using an onscreen keyboard, you have an enter key there...

Comment: With the onscreen keyboard.... but sometimes I do not type, I am reading articles and when I see a term I do not know I copy that term and paste it into the search box and then I have to open the on screen keyboard or go to my pc and press enter.